# Is it possible to use `wp_schedule_event` with real cronjobs?

Tags: cron, wp-cron

I hate the way Wordpress Cron Jobs run, so I disabled them:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

and want to run a real cron job instead:

```
wget http://www.myserver.com/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

---

Question: can I then use `wp_schedule_event` to schedule my own stuff? Will they be triggered by the cron job?

---

Also, can I trigger the cronjob without wget?

Comment: There was an answer with a discussion, and it just vanished. So, is this doable, or not?

Comment: It vanished, cause it was plainly wrong and I deleted it. `wp-cron.php` calls `wp-load.php`, hence can access all of WPs (frontend) functions and hence is runnable on its own (kudos @Otto). Now it's just a matter of triggering it from cron. `wget` and a URL will only be required if you wanted to run it from your local (or any other remote) machine (which would be pointless). Run it from your server's cron with an absolute path to it and you ought to be set.

Comment: @JohannesPille - So will triggering it directly though a cronjob run `wp_schedule_event` actions?